# Is there any way to get data of (Yesterday) withing a particular timestamp using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I'm using mysql workbench, And i need to retrive data of yesterday, but i want the data from a particular timestamp for eg data from 00:00:00 to 12:00:00 how can i do that? And i dont want to change the date everyday.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> retrive data of yesterday .. from 00:00:00 to 12:00:00

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE row_timestamp BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY     -- yesterday, 00:00
                        AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 HOUR;  -- yesterday, 12:00
```

Comment: Can we store this in a variable , so that we don't have to change the (time) every single time before running the query ( BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE -INTERVAL 12 HOUR )

Comment: @Yogesh Both `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY` and `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 HOUR` are constants (CURRENT_DATE value is a constant value of the execution starting timestamp, not actual run-time value which can change during the execution) which are calculated once during the execution plan building. They are not evaluated while the query is executed. And we don't need to store them somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Man... can you tell me how can i get the values of last week (within a particular timestamp) just like you've done for yesterday

Comment: @Yogesh *how can i get the values of last week* Unclear... do you need a day which is a week ago? if so then simply alter the amount of substracted period - 7*24=168 hours for lower bound and 7*24-12=156 hours for upper bound.

Comment: for eg - Today is Monday Now i need the date of last Monday from 00:00:00am to 12:00:00pm

Comment: @Yogesh As I have said above, ```.. BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 168 HOURS AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 156 HOURS ..```.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE(row_timestamp) = DATE(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
AND HOUR(row_timestamp) < 12
```

Comment: This is fullscan.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality answers on Stack Overflow. This answer could be improved with an explanation as to how this solves OP's problem presented in the question, such as breaking down the query.